# How to replace string sequence in input if it contains something from array with an element from array?

Tags: java, arrays, string, input, replace

I know, that today's question is a bit complex but here's the explanation :

I'm working on little program for my teacher, where i have to find out , if input, that i wrote to console contains these strings : https://pastebin.com/MiKUru0y. Then i have to replace them with correct forms of chemical elements and finally write it to the console.

For example :

If input was - kofola, output is : KOFOLa

Or if input was - AGATYAM, output is : AgAtYAm.

So if a.toLowerCase() contained something from String[] elements.toLowerCase(), i have to replace it with a word from String[] elements.

I wrote a code by myself but i just don't know how to replace it properly.

```
public class converter {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String[] elements = {"Ac", "Ag", "Al", "Am", "Ar", "As", "At", "Au", "B", "Ba", "Be", "Bh", "Bi", "Bk", "Br", "C", "Ca", "Cd", "Ce", "Cf", "Cl", "Cm", "Cn", "Co", "Cr", "Cs", "Cu", "Db", "Ds", "Dy", "Er", "Es", "Eu", "F", "Fe", "Fl", "Fm", "Fr", "Ga", "Gd", "Ge", "H", "He", "Hf", "Hg", "Ho", "Hs", "I", "In", "Ir", "K", "Kr", "La", "Li", "Lr", "Lu", "Lv", "Md", "Mg", "Mn", "Mo", "Mt", "N", "Na", "Nb", "Nd", "Ne", "Ni", "No", "Np", "O", "Os", "P", "Pa", "Pb", "Pd", "Pm", "Po", "Pr", "Pt", "Pu", "Ra", "Rb", "Re", "Rf", "Rg", "Rh", "Rn", "Ru", "S", "Sb", "Sc", "Se", "Sg", "Si", "Sm", "Sn", "Sr", "Ta", "Tb", "Tc", "Te", "Th", "Ti", "Tl", "Tm", "U", "Uuo", "Uup", "Uus", "Uut", "V", "W", "Xe", "Y", "Yb", "Zn", "Zr"};
        String a=in.readLine();
        int p=0;

        for(int i =0; i<elements.length;i++){
              if(a.toLowerCase().contains(elements[i].toLowerCase())){
            }
        }
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

If the input didn't contain a word from array, then write "can't replace".

Thank you for your help.

Comment: you can built 2 level Trie (search for java Tries on goggle) , you can modify to work with only  2 levels,

Comment: @Sendi_t a trie for this is overkill IMHO.

Comment: @jrook, look now OP wants some validation. 2 level Trie would be natural, I think, based on what OP is trying to do :)

Comment: Should string "os" be translated to "OS" or "Os" ?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
        boolean found = false;

        ...

        for () {
            if (a.toLowerCase().contains(elements[i].toLowerCase())) {
                int idx = a.toLowerCase().indexOf(elements[i].toLowerCase());
                if (idx != -1) {
                    String replace = a.substring(idx, idx+elements[i].length());
                    a = a.replace(replace, elements[i]);
                    found = true;
                }
            }
         }

         ...

         if (!found) {
             System.out.println("can't replace");
         } else {
              System.out.println(a);
         }
```

I didn't test all cases, but this should get you close.

Comment: It's okay but there's a little problem.
when the input is for example "vinea" output should be "can't replace" instead of "VINea"

Comment: @JakubKolesár Please take a few minutes to look at [this thread](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions). The generally accepted policy on homework is  to give a nudge in the right direction not give a fully working code (i.e. basically doing it for you).